# Is saying "is this (name)'s phone?" rude in business conversation?

Tags: politeness, conversation

Is the following sentence rude in business conversation?

> Is this (name)'s phone?

I want to ask if the speaker is the person who I'm looking for.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Pika. I've edited a bit your post to highlight the sentence. Also notice that I've changed the determiner that you have used before person. You're looking for a SPECIFIC person [the one whose name you're asking] not just A person.

Comment: @RubioRic Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: So why don't you ask "Is this (name)?" It might be their phone, but someone else picking up.

Comment: @DanielRoseman  Thank you! In korea, we often ask, 'Is this (name)'s phone?' so I thought it's same in other  countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether it is "rude" or not depends on your tone. By itself, *"Is this (name)'s phone?"* does not have a connotation of rudeness.

Note that we usually say

> *Hi, is this John?* or *Hi, am I speaking to John?*

Comment: I get it. Thank you!